# How is the motive/aim of irony 'exclusiveness'?

Tags: meaning-in-context

[Source:](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=humor&allowed_in_frame=0) p 241, *A Dictionary of Modern English Usage, The Classic First Edition* (2010)
by H. W. Fowler, David Crystal

> [irony (n.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=irony&searchmode=none) [...] Figurative use for "condition opposite to what might be expected; contradictory circumstances" is from 1640s.

In the Source's table, under the **device** of IRONY, the **motive/aim** is listed as 'exclusiveness'.
I know the definitions of 'exclusiveness', but which is the right one? Please help me disambiguate.

I quote the definition of 'irony' above, which I already understand and so ask NOT about

Comment: Is there a particular reason you've chosen to ignore half of the definition?

Comment: @Catija Sorry, which half?

Answer (score 2):

I believe Fowler may have been referring to **dramatic irony** which is a literary technique in which the audience understands more than the characters, and therefore get a different meaning from what the characters say and do than what the characters "intended". In that way, the characters on stage are excluded from understanding what's going on.

He could also be referring to **verbal irony**, which is a rhetorical technique in which what someone says does not match their actual meaning, where their actual meaning may be conveyed through other means like intonation or visual cues, or through inherent conflicts in the words themselves ("as clear as mud"). This kind of irony is sometimes not understood by all of the audience, which creates a kind of "exclusive club" of the people that understand.

Comment: So that would make it basically an in-joke, then, the exclusiveness of which is a little more explicit but similar.

Answer (score 0):

First, as a polite criticism, let me just say that your inclusion of the definition for irony, rather than the inclusion of the table in the source (or even removing any quote entirely and just providing a link) is rather disorienting. This seems to have been evidenced by other posts on this thread. My suggestion is that you avoid including any information that is completely irrelevant to the question.

Second, since you have actually linked the definition of *humor,* things are made much more clear, since we're speaking in the context of humor. I am not a humorist or a comedian, so I am not well-versed in the more specific nuances of each type of humor. It might seem like I'm rambling here, but there's a lot of different things I need to talk about.

There is one thing I can tell you for certain: *sarcasm,* also listed on the referenced table, is a type of irony -- specifically, verbal irony. Irony is a complex concept to grasp in English, but the simplest definition is that it is when something unexpected happens in an expected event's place, often resulting in comedy. Sarcasm is strictly when the speaker says a statement in which the opposite is meant; for instance, a soccer (or football for non-Americans) player gets hit in the face with the ball, after which he says "Well, that felt great." This is a type of irony, since he said the opposite of what was expected. However, irony encompasses more than just opposites. Irony is often the result of a funny coincidence, but irony in the context of humor is deliberated in advance (by the humorist), which means it often has a deeper meaning. In the traditional sense of humor, however, it's rather hard for me to imagine how irony can be used as a tool of exclusion -- at least, in the majority of its usage. Sarcasm seems to fit that mold rather appropriately, but it too has an entry on the table, which is slightly more confusing.

This brings me to a non-humor related topic. Irony is actually quite a hot topic, especially in modern American culture. I don't know how old the page you linked is, but "exclusiveness" strikes me as an interesting choice, since I would not have thought of irony as a tool of exclusion until recently. Many youngsters in American culture find it very fashionable to do things ironically, with no clear intent to provoke humor. Specifically, they often do or wear things that suggest that they lead a different lifestyle, often one that they deem worthy of mockery. This has often been used as an effective means of excluding unwanted potential members of a clique or group; partially due to the offensiveness of the mockery (if grasped by the victim) and partially due to the fact that the ironic gesture in question is often indecipherable or confusing, which turns off many. That's the most appropriate usage of irony I can think of that would fall under a motive of "exclusiveness."